# Typescript + Angular: assigning a a type to Type<T> fails

Tags: angular, typescript, types

I'm struggling with assigning a type.

In the example below I want to be able to work with a type I provide to the function `createMock_UserService`. It works fine if I call the function with the desired type but it doesn't when I don't provide a Type and want to assign it `Child` manually it fails with the error noted in the code below.

```
export class Parent {

}

export class Child extends Parent {

}

export function createMock_UserService<T extends Parent>(type?: Type<T>) {

  if(!type) {
    // this fails -> Type 'Child' is not assignable to type 'T'
    type = Child;
  }

  // do stuff with type
  injector.get(type);
}

// calling it works
createMock_UserService(Child);

// this doesn't
createMock_UserService();
```

`Type<T>` is defined as (this is angular's code and typescript core)

```
export declare const Type: FunctionConstructor;
interface FunctionConstructor {
    /**
      * Creates a new function.
      * @param args A list of arguments the function accepts.
      */
    new(...args: string[]): Function;
    (...args: string[]): Function;
    readonly prototype: Function;
}
```

How can I make this work?
I have the feeling I'm missing something obvious.

[Here's the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t9wkhd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Can you post the the declaration for `Type<T>` ?

Comment: Actually Type and `Child` are not same `Type` is a new generic type and `Child` is one of the type supported in `T` of `Type<T>`

Comment: but why does this `createMock_UserService(Child);`  work?
I added the declare of Type<T>

Comment: from your declaration `Type` is not generic at all you have not used `T` anywhere

Comment: I updated the code to reflect that I need to use angulars `injector.get` which expects a `Type<T>` and I tried to restrict `T`.
So, how would it work correctly?

Comment: can you create a stackbltiz demo

Comment: When you are not passing `type` variable the value is null as it's optional param. So the type of `T` in this case does not match with `Child`. Why are you keeping it as optional if you need to call injector anyway.

Comment: I added the stackblitz. What's really strange TS complains but the code seems to work anyway.

I'm keeping it as optional because I want to provide a default value (which will be used in most cases)

Comment: Then you can keep a default value function instead of optional.

Comment: yes, but it doesn't matter because the error remains the same.
EDIT: I think I misread. You mean a complete separate function, right?
This is a possible solution. But I really want to know how I can, if it's possible, achieve this in a more dynamic fashion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it way more complicated that it has to be.

Here's how it works (slightly refactored)

```
export function createMock_UserService(injector: Injector, type: Type<UserService<UserWithPermissions>> = UserServiceMock): jasmine.Spy {
  return spyOn(injector.get(type), 'getCurrentUser');
}
```

Not using generics anymore just plain, simple inheritance.